# Problema con GUI en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, interfaz-gráfica

Recurro aquí a ver si me pueden iluminar con esto de Java y las GUI que estoy aprendiendo recién.

Estoy tratando de hacer una GUI sencilla de 3 secciones (encabezado, contenido y pie).

Genere el siguiente código (ojo, no es el programa completo y se que hay variables sin usar)

```
package grilla;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Remun extends JFrame{

private JFrame ventana;
private JButton sumaHab, sumaDesc;
private JLabel texto1, tituloEnc;
private JCheckBox check1;
private JTextField ingreso1,totalHab,totalDesc,totalAPagar;
private JPanel panelEnc,panelFoot;

public Remun(){
    pantalla();
    encabezado();
    footer();

}

public void encabezado(){
    panelEnc=new JPanel();
    tituloEnc=new JLabel("Sistema de Remuneraciones");
    panelEnc.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panelEnc.add(tituloEnc);
}

public void footer(){
    panelFoot=new JPanel();
    sumaHab=new JButton("Sumar Haberes");
    sumaDesc=new JButton("Sumar Descuentos");
    panelFoot.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panelFoot.add(sumaHab);
    panelFoot.add(totalHab);
    panelFoot.add(sumaDesc);
    panelFoot.add(totalDesc);
    panelFoot.add(totalAPagar);
}

public void pantalla(){
    ventana=new JFrame("Remuneraciones");
    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventana.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    ventana.add(panelEnc);
    ventana.add(panelFoot);
    ventana.pack();
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Remun g1 = new Remun();
}
```

}

Pero cuando quiero previsualizar los avances este no se ejecuta.

Este es el error que obtengo.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1095)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1007)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:567)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:419)
at grilla.Remun.pantalla(Remun.java:46)
at grilla.Remun.<init>(Remun.java:17)
at grilla.Remun.main(Remun.java:54)
Java Result: 1
```

Por si es importante, adjunto las versiones de Netbeans, JDK y JRE

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)

Java: 1.8.0_191; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.191-b12

Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_191-b12

Saludos y agradecimientos de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`panelEnc` y `panelFoot` no estan definidos cuando los añades y por eso dan excepción.

Cambia tu constructor por

```
public Remun(){
     encabezado();
     footer();
     pantalla();
}
```

Comment: Modifiqué el constructor según mencionas, sin embrago, sigue lanzándome una excepción. 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1095)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:419)
    at grilla.Remun.footer(Remun.java:35)
    at grilla.Remun.<init>(Remun.java:18)
    at grilla.Remun.main(Remun.java:53)
    Java Result: 1

Comment: ¿Que excepción?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1095) at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:419) at grilla.Remun.footer(Remun.java:35) at grilla.Remun.<init>(Remun.java:18) at grilla.Remun.main(Remun.java:53) Java Result: 1`

Comment: El problema es similar, cualquier componente que añadas tiene que estar inicializado. En tu segundo error da porque `sumaHab`es null.

Comment: Efectivamente, el problema eran las variables JTextField en el método footer.
`totalHab=new JTextField(10);
totalDesc=new JTextField(10);
totalAPagar=new JTextField(10);`
Una vez agregadas el programa se ejecuta.
Agradecido por la ayuda.